# MimeKit howto base64 encode attachment filenames

Tags: c#, mimekit

MimeKit defaults to generate attachment filenames using "encoded-words"

"Testfile with æ ø og å.pdf" becomes 
name*=iso-8859-1''Testfile%20with%20%E6%20%F8%20og%20%E5.pdf

I would like to get
name="=?utf-8?B?VGVzdGZpbGUgd2l0aCDDpiDDuCBvZyDDpS5wZGY=?="

Here is some sample code.
You can see the result in the generated eml-file

```
        MimeKit.AttachmentCollection vedhaeftedefiler = new MimeKit.AttachmentCollection();

        vedhaeftedefiler.Add(@"d:\temp\Testfile with æ ø og å.pdf");

        var email = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
        email.From.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("John Doe", "john@example.com"));
        email.Subject = "testsubject";
        email.To.Add(new MimeKit.MailboxAddress("John Doe", "john@example.com"));

        var bodyBuilder = new MimeKit.BodyBuilder();
        bodyBuilder.TextBody = "Hello John";

        foreach (var a in vedhaeftedefiler)
        {
            bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(a);
        }
        email.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
        email.Body.Prepare(MimeKit.EncodingConstraint.EightBit);
        email.WriteTo(@"d:\temp\MimeKitTest_ " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMdd hhmmss") + ".eml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override behavior of the parameter encoding like this:

```
var attachments = new AttachmentCollection ();
var attachment = attachments.Add(@"d:\temp\Testfile with æ ø og å.pdf");

foreach (var parameter in attachment.ContentType.Parameters)
    parameter.EncodingMethod = ParameterEncodingMethod.Rfc2047;

foreach (var parameter in attachment.ContentDisposition.Parameters)
    parameter.EncodingMethod = ParameterEncodingMethod.Rfc2047;
```

Comment: Now it get:
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="=?iso-8859-1?q?Testfile_with_=E6_=F8?=
 =?iso-8859-1?q?_og_=E5=2Epdf?="

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?iso-8859-1?q?Testfile_with_?=
 =?iso-8859-1?b?5iD4IG9nIOUucGRm?="

Which works in Outlook 2016 :)

Any way to force UTF8 encoding instead of iso-8859-1?

Comment: It’ll only use utf8 if it won’t fit into iso-8859-1.